# Performace: multiple conditions in one IF or nested IF?

Tags: php, performance

(PHP)
for example, i have functions,which execute heavy queries and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
 is there any performance difference:

```
if ( cond1()  &&  cond2() && cond3() && cond4())
```

or

```
if (cond1()){
  if (cond2()){

  }
}
```

because, in the last case, if `cond1()` is false, then it doesnt execute the other conditions.. is same for the first example?

Comment: No performance difference. In both cases, if `cond1()` returns false, none of the other functions will be called.

Comment: If only there was a simple way to test that… *cough* `false && print('hello');`

Comment: I have run tests on a PHP sandbox and found that on PHP7 the timings are identical but on PHP 5.6 there are different timings for the differnt IF syntax structure. I was going to elaborate here on that before duplicate locking....

Comment: @Martin The byte code may be ever so slightly different, but logically they're identical and there's no performance difference *in the big picture*, i.e. whether `cond2()` gets executed at all or not. Or can you contradict that?

Comment: I found that on [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) running 10k `for` loops on PHP5.6.20 and 7.0.2 there was a very sight difference of around `0.0002` seconds for two loops (1 for each syntax statement (4 `If`'s each)) but the more I think about it the more I suspect the difference is caused elsewhere in the system. Too many unknowns and far too small a variation to be significant. Overall it seemed to show there was a small delay in having all arguments in a single `if` condition. Just interesting, nothing more. @deceze

Comment: @deceze I will put some details in an answer on the question you linked this one too...

Comment: frustratingly enough, if I swap the order of the loops it doesn't swap the timings, the second loop is always slower than the first, no matter the syntax so no, I have no interesting conclusion after all. :-(

Comment: @Martin My main interes was, if the second `cond2()` was executed. so, it is not executed, right?

Comment: In that respect they're both identical processes, yes

Answer (score 1):

No this has no performance differences.

In this example when condition 1 fails, it doesn't execute the second condition

```
if ( cond1()  &&  cond2() && cond3() && cond4())
```